# How to use PHP to connect to a proxy server?

Tags: php, proxy

I need to use PHP to connect to a URL via a proxy server. I will be grateful if you could point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [CURLOPT_PROXY](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php) from [PHP curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)